# Installing Ubuntu 23.10 on my new SSD and setting /home to my HDD without erasing

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd

I'm a linux guy and I'm new to storage splitting between a SSD and an HDD so I need help.

I have to add a new 240GB SSD to a system where is already installade a 512GB HDD.
Can I install a new ubuntu distribution, from a bootable USB flash drive, to my SSD and setting `/home` to my old HDD without erasing the contents of it?

Comment: Install normally, (leave /home on the SSD, then google "move /home". I'd also AVOID to "just copy" old settings into the new installation. Re-think what the effects might be.

Comment: Simply: install Ubuntu on the SDD and mount the HDD in your /home/username as another directory.

Comment: Yes, you can add it later (*after the installation on SSD*) in `/etc/fstab` as `/home` and delete the `/home` created on the SSD during installation ... That's one way ... As a side note, your `/home` on the HDD will slow down your startup time especially when loading userspace i.e. after login ... So if your main purpose adding an SSD is speed, you might have to lower your expectations for that.

Comment: If a bit more advanced, you can keep /home, but only the normally hidden  ( . ) files in / and link folders from a data partition back into /home. You have to mount data partition with fstab, give yourself ownership & permissions to data partition, and link folders in data partition into /home.  That way all the user settings in /home are still faster, only loading data is a bit slower from HDD.